# createReadStream error: "OK, Open"

Tags: node.js

I have the following snippet of code that is in a function that gets called multiple times for different files.

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
readStream.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Regularly, some files, but not all, will error with the following message:

```
OK, open '{filename}'
```

The exact number of errors isn't always the same, but it's roughly the same amount. And it's not always the same files.  I am processing ~6500 files and get ~1150 errors.

What does this error mean? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OS, node version and some more code could help...

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my linux machine. But this: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.javascript.nodejs/38045 sounds like your problem. There it is discussed to be a problem on windows machines and the limit of simultaneously opened files. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Sounds like that is what I am seeing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Error: OK" when using fs.readFile() in Node.js (after some iteration of about a hundred thousand)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425458/error-ok-when-using-fs-readfile-in-node-js-after-some-iteration-of-about-a)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [graceful-fs](https://npmjs.org/package/graceful-fs). This is a node module which abstracts all the fs calls you wish to make with some addtionaly features. Especially useful in windows systems.

Usage is dead simple:

```
# Install
$ npm install graceful-fs

# Usage (in foo.js)
var fs = require('graceful-fs');
```