# fs.readFile anomaly

Tags: node.js

Trying to run a script that opens a bunch of files asynchronously and reads their content.  I am getting an error where `fs.readFile`'s callback comes in with no data, yet the file is there, and is not currently being opened by anything else. Totally confused.

The error is:

> Error: OK, open
>   'D:\Workspace\fasttrack\public\cloudmade\images\998\256\6\31\61.png'

More info:

The program runs through a loop that has a bunch of objects in it that look like this:

```
newObject = {
    filePath:filePath,
    scanPixels:function(parent){
        ....
    }
}
```

The loop calls each object's `scanPixels` function, which then does an `fs.readFile` on the `parent.filePath`

Here is the for loop

```
for(var index=0;index<objects.length;index++){
    objects[index].scanPixels(objects[index]);
}
```

The scanPixels function is essentially this:

```
scanPixels:function(parent){

            png_js.decode(parent.filePath, function(pixels){

                ...more stuff
```

And in the png_js file:

```
PNG.decode = function(path, fn) {

  return fs.readFile(path, function(err, file) {

    var png;
    png = new PNG(file);
    return png.decode(function(pixels) {
      return fn(pixels);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Gonna need to see more code. Is your loop a "for" loop, or are you using "forEach"?

Comment: Are you running this on Windows? I remember a similar problem of another user someday. I think it was a problem with too many simultaneous opened files at which windows has some problems with. edit: I've found the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210978/createreadstream-error-ok-open

Comment: @Cromax Yes interesting you mentioned that.  I had that problem in another program a few days ago with too many files open and found the post you are talking about, so I thought that was happening here, but I setup a counter to log how many were currently opened everytime another was opened and it happily sailed past 2048 ( The windows limit).  Though that is the limit for open streams, is that the same for readFile? I guess does readFile use the same type of stream? If so, I might need to check on that again

Comment: also kill explorer.exe .. it could be thumbnailing under explorer is locking the files intermittently to generate thumbnails (its happened to me several times when ive had the folder open with the images and i couldnt delete the images)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Error: OK" when using fs.readFile() in Node.js (after some iteration of about a hundred thousand)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425458/error-ok-when-using-fs-readfile-in-node-js-after-some-iteration-of-about-a)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that fs.readFile does not return a value. You would want fs.readFileSync for that

```
var buffer1 = fs.fileReadSync('./hello1.txt');

var buffer2;
fs.fileRead('./hello2.txt', function (err, file) {
    buffer = file;
});
```