# error handling on readFileSync in node.js

Tags: node.js, error-handling, synchronous, fs

I have this code

```
var fd = fs.openSync(filePath,"r");
var fr = fs.readSync(fd, buffer, 0, size, 0);
```

and it throws error like that

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: OK, open 'C:\Users\iahmed16\Desktop\eclipse WS\test\images\af31a9e0a98939be82f887b0005c21752e71425e.jpg'
```

- how to handle this error ??
- what's the meaning of the error if you know ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error seems to mean that you have [too many file descriptions open](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16425458).

You have to make sure at some point that you [`close()`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_close_fd_callback) them.

```
var fd = fs.openSync(filePath,"r");
var fr = fs.readSync(fd, buffer, 0, size, 0);
fs.closeSync(fd);
```

As for how to handle the error, you can use [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) with [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)n errors:

```
try {
    var fd = fs.openSync(filePath,"r");
    var fr = fs.readSync(fd, buffer, 0, size, 0);
    fs.closeSync(fd);
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Error:', e);
}
```

Comment: I'm using try...catch ... but some errors force the app to crash and not enter in the catch part. or that means I have error in another part of the code ???